# Algorithm - Miminum swaps to adjust matrix

Tags: algorithm

I am working on a algorithm to calculate the minimum swaps to adjust a matrix to meet specific requirement.
Given a M x N matrix with all elements either 0 or 1. Now by swapping two elements several times, we want the matrix to meet requirement that no '1' element adjacent to each other.
In other words, if element at (m, n) is 1, then element at (m-1, n), (m, n-1), (m+1, n) and (m, n+1) must all be 0.

Now we need an algorithm to calculate the minimum swaps to adjust the matrix.

For example, when original matrix is like below:

```
1010
0001
0111
0010
0000
```

The result should be 2, with possible adjusted matrix like below:

```
1010
0001
0100
0010
0101
```

I am struggling for this problem for several days and have no direction to start with. Can anybody share any good idea or direction for this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you familiar with [8 Queens puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle)?  You can use the same approach.

Comment: @PM77-1: thanks for your comments! I used to solve 8 Queens puzzle using backtrack approach, but I did not see clear connection between 8 queens puzzle and this problem. Can you please elaborate if possible? thanks!

Comment: I was merely suggesting to use backtracking here as well.